# Create function to compute an average of 3 values

Tags: postgresql, function, average

I'm trying to write a function in postgre sql to take an average across three columns. I have written the following function:

```
create function xcol_avg (col1, col2, col3)
returns numeric as $$

begin

return (coalesce(col1, 0) + coalesce(col2,0) +coalesce(col3, 0))/
case when (col 1 is null or col1 = 0 then 0 else 1 end +
case when (col 2 is null or col2 = 0 then 0 else 1 end +
case when (col 3 is null or col3 = 0 then 0 else 1 end;

end
```

What is the problem with my code? Also, is there a way to get the function to return null if it ends up dividing by 0? Any help is really appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Kristen, I've added my answer. Hope this gives you enough information on the subject. You have various issues with your function. I suggest you review the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can make a function that will use a variable number of arguments and depending on their number compute the average. In [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html) there's a word `VARIADIC` for such things:

> SQL functions can be declared to accept variable numbers of arguments, so long as all the "optional" arguments are of the same data type

**Function code:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION xcol_avg(numeric, VARIADIC numeric[])
  RETURNS numeric
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
  IMMUTABLE
AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT AVG(vals) FROM unnest($2 || ARRAY[$1]) t(vals));
END;
$$;
```

**Use case with different number of arguments:**

```
select xcol_avg(1,6); -- returns 3.5
select xcol_avg(1,5.5,4); -- returns 3.5
select xcol_avg(1,2,3,4,5,6,7); -- returns 4
```

Click on this <kbd>[**Button**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5e8f2/1)</kbd> to try this online.

**Explanation:**

- Marking a function as [`IMMUTABLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-volatility.html) improves the execution time by allowing the optimizer to pre-evaluate the function. Immutable functions cannot modify the database and are guaranteed to always return the same results when called with the same input.
- Declaring the last parameter of a function as [`VARIADIC`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html) which has to be of an array type lets you provide optional arguments that will be passed to the function as an array. Note that you don't explicitly write the array, you just list your parameters as you normally would.
- [`unnest()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) is a function that returns a set of rows by expanding an array. In other words it's "unpacking" the array elements into separate rows
- [`||`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE) is an array operator that provides the array-to-array concatenation. Here it serves the purpose of connecting the first (required) argument with the rest given in a `VARIADIC` array.
- [`AVG()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) is an aggregate function that computes an average of all input values. In our case it would take "unpacked" rows from a column named `vals` and compute the average.

With this solution you don't need to worry about dividing by zero, as at least one argument is required and `avg()` is doing the job you wanted to do manually by building up the denominator.

**Apply it in a query:**

This function would also work for computing an average of multiple columns in a row. Consider a table `tbl` with columns `name, cost1, cost2, cost3` and below statement:

```
SELECT 
  name, cost1, cost2, cost3,
  xcol_avg(cost1, cost2, cost3) AS average_cost
FROM tbl
```

For more general information about `CREATE FUNCTION` check [the resourceful documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html).